# What does shallow_path has in Rails routes do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In the below example, isn't the route already scoped to `foo` already so that any url will follow the pattern of `www.app/foo/...`? Why is the `shallow_path` still needed? What does it do?

```
Procore::Application.routes.draw do
  # Nontab routes
  scope ':foo', :shallow_path => ':foo' do
    get '/.../:id',  :to => '...#show', :as => '...'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the shallow_path does not do anything.

You are right, because of the `scope` the route will already be at `/:foo/.../:id`.

The whole point of the `shallow` option is to make the `resources` route only use `:index, :new`, and `:create` for the deeply nested route, and to not use the deeply nested route for `:show`, `:edit`, `:update`, and `:destroy`.

The `shallow_path` argument allows you to specify the prefix that you'd like to add to the member routes.

From the docs:

```
scope shallow_path: "sekret" do
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments, shallow: true
  end
end
```

Would produce these routes:

```
HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action   Named Helper
GET         /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)    comments#index  article_comments_path
POST        /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)    comments#create article_comments_path
GET         /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)comments#new    new_article_comment_path
GET         /sekret/comments/:id/edit(.:format)         comments#edit   edit_comment_path
GET         /sekret/comments/:id(.:format)              comments#show   comment_path
PATCH/PUT   /sekret/comments/:id(.:format)             comments#update  comment_path
DELETE      /sekret/comments/:id(.:format)            comments#destroy  comment_path
```

Note how `/sekret/` is in front of the `member` routes, but is not in front of the `collection` actions.

See section 2.7.2 in [Rails Routing Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Where it states in the intro paragraph:

> One way to avoid deep nesting (as recommended above) is to generate
>   the collection actions scoped under the parent, so as to get a sense
>   of the hierarchy, but to not nest the member actions. In other words,
>   to only build routes with the minimal amount of information to
>   uniquely identify the resource...

Comment: The whole point of the **shallow** option is to make the resources route only nest the collection routes (:index, :new, and :create).  The point of `shallow_path` is to prefix the member routes (:show, :edit, :update, and :destroy). I think you understand the concepts but this answer needs some editing.

Comment: @max Yes, I see what you mean. I edited it. Thanks for pointing that out.